# Creating a class in python?

Tags: python, class

What is a difference between these examples and which one should I use:

```
class Foo:

class Foo():

class Foo(object):
```

I think my question is unique, because in a linked proposed duplicate question it doesn't say the difference between `class Foo:` and `class Foo():`

Comment: a little research before asking would not hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class Foo:` is essentially a syntactic shortcut for `class Foo():`. The difference between `class Foo():` and `class Foo(object):` only exists in Python 2, where the former creates an old-style class and the latter creates a new-style class. In Python 3, all three are identical, as only new-style classes exist.